# Hibernate not saving object to database

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I've been trying to set up a little hibernate/spring MVC project.

I've gotten the Spring .jsp page to display data from the database, but i cannot figure out how to have hibernate save the objects to the database.

Here is my (relevant) Code:

GroupDAOImpl.java (the method)

```
@Override
public void saveGroup(Group group){
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(group);

    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

HelloController.java Method:

```
 public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Group group) throws Exception {
    groupDAO.saveGroup(group);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
}
```

jsp Page:

```
<form:form action="add.htm" commandName="group">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>group Name :</td>
        <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Register"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Log from the Server:

```
Hibernate: insert into groups (id, name, shoppingList_id) values (default, ?, ?)
```

Debugger Value of "group" in GroupDAOImpl saving method:

```
id = 2
name = "jjjj"
```

Any ideas? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: As I understand the problem is that data is not saved in database? How is your datasource defined - in Spring or it is independent on Spring. What database are you using?

Comment: What does the `Group` class looks like? Is the object already existing or is it a new instance? How is it saved in the DAO?

Comment: I use a derby database and the database is configured in spring `<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/hiber-db"/>
        <property name="username" value="oe"/>
        <property name="password" value="oe"/>
    </bean>`

Answer (score 0):

Actually we see the SQL requests on the log:

```
Hibernate: insert into groups (id, name, shoppingList_id) values (default, ?, ?)
```

I guess you don't explain well and you expect it to be an SQL update query of your existing object.

If you want to update the object, the Group instance provided by SpringMVC binding should know the object id.
Actually the form dosn't send the Group id so your application can't know which object should be updated.

And even with knowing the ID, it would be the Session.merge and not Session.save to call :)

Comment: well there is 1 item already in the database, but i want to add another one, not update an existing one. the id is not yet set since it is supposed to be set by hibernate through `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know hibernate properties need to be prefixed with hibernate, like

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
```

fix that, that could be your problem